# Local Notification with Notifee does not displaying in Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-notifications, uilocalnotification

I am having an issue where the local notification is not displaying in android though it is displaying in IOS. I have created permissions and battery optimization check to see if that is the problem. The notification does make a sound and appear shows a little square in the upper left that if I click and drag does show the local notification. I am using an emulator right now and I have tried it on a real device.

This is the way I am calling the notification.

```
      <Button
         title="Trigger Push Notification"
         size="large"
         onPress={() => onDisplayNotification('default', 'Default Channel', 'Spotback 
         Android', 'Local push notification')}
              />
```

This is is the Notifee component.

```
import notifee, { AndroidStyle, AuthorizationStatus, Notification } from '@notifee/react-native';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

export const onDisplayNotification = async (id, name, title, body, smallIcon?) => {
  // Request permissions (required for iOS)
  await notifee.requestPermission();

  const settings = await notifee.getNotificationSettings();

  const batteryOptimizationEnabled = await notifee.isBatteryOptimizationEnabled();
  if (batteryOptimizationEnabled) {
    // 2. ask your users to disable the feature
    Alert.alert(
      'Restrictions Detected',
      'To ensure notifications are delivered, please disable battery optimization for the app.',
      [
        // 3. launch intent to navigate the user to the appropriate screen
        {
          text: 'OK, open settings',
          onPress: async () => await notifee.openBatteryOptimizationSettings(),
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel',
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  }
  if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED) {
    console.log('Notification permissions has been authorized');
  } else if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.DENIED) {
    console.log('Notification permissions has been denied');
  }
  // }

  // Create a channel (required for Android)
  const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
    id,
    name,
  });

  await notifee.displayNotification({
    title,
    body,
    android: {
      channelId,
      smallIcon,
      pressAction: {
        id,
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for this ?

Comment: @Prateek no I haven’t. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have precisely the same issue and still cannot figure it out... this post is quite old were you able to find a solution for this? It would be much appreciated if you could share it, please. Also I would recommend adding #notifee to the question since I think it's related to this library. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works just fine for IOS but android is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Please change your channel id (default) and channel name (Default Channel) to something else like:
id: custom_channel
name: custom_channel

Comment: I have tried that with no luck. Can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 3):

from documentation:

https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/android/appearance

The highest importance level applied to a channel/notification. Notifications will appear on-top of applications, allowing direct interaction without pulling down the notification shade. This level should only be used for urgent notifications, such as incoming phone calls, messages etc, which require immediate attention.

```
import notifee, { AndroidImportance } from '@notifee/react-native';

const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
  id: 'important',
  name: 'Important Notifications',
  importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
});

await notifee.displayNotification({
  title: 'Your account requires attention',
  body: 'You are overdue payment on one or more of your accounts!',
  android: {
    channelId,
    importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
  },
});
```

Comment: One addition here add sound property in createChannel function as well if you want sound with notification

Answer (score 2):

Try to create the channel like this:

```
const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
   ...,
   importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH, //Add this line.
});
```